# How to retrieve data which only belongs to a specified user?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function

I got this page called summary which basically shows the user list of all the exam that they took and how long they spend, etc. What I am trying to do is to only pull the data based on the user id. So if I have a person called simon and another person called mark, I don't want simon to be seeing marks data. Only show the user what they have.

This is my function  :

```
function get_student_summary () {
    $data = array();

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT a.*,b.*,c.*,d.*,e.* FROM mock_exam_quiz a, mock_exam_student_summary b, mock_exam_users c, mock_exam_questions d, mock_exam_category e WHERE a.quiz_id = b.exam_id AND c.user_id = b.user_id AND d.question_id = b.question_id AND e.category_id = b.category_id");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $data [] = $row;
    }

    return $data;
}
```

This is a snippet of how the user will be viewing the exam details on the summary page. [Screenshot](https://gyazo.com/e149ed3e7652a3e282178e8fce0f04c3)

This image below is a screenshot of my database table where I am storing all the data. [Database screenshot](https://gyazo.com/f73859eee74b4cac3b51cfceb6b9d281). If you look at the user_id there are two different user's and as I have mentioned I want the user to see the one that belongs to them. I don't want to show any other user's data to other users.

I am sorry if I have confused anyone or not explained in detail the problem, but please do ask if you have any questions. I been stuck on this problem for the past few days and I appreciate any help from you guys.

Comment: **DO NOT USE** mysql_* . It has been removed in PHP7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'll have to do is pass the ID through the function and use that ID in your query.

Your function will look something like this:

```
function get_student_summary ($id) {
    $data = array();

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT a.*,b.*,c.*,d.*,e.* FROM mock_exam_quiz a, mock_exam_student_summary b, mock_exam_users c, mock_exam_questions d, mock_exam_category e WHERE a.quiz_id = b.exam_id AND c.user_id = b.user_id AND d.question_id = b.question_id AND e.category_id = b.category_id AND c.user_id='".$id"'");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $data [] = $row;
    }

    return $data;
}
```

You'll notice at the end of the query where I put `AND c.user_id='".id"'`.  I have not done PHP in a long time, but I think you should either be using `mysqli` or `pdo` for your queries as well.

**Edit:**

So when you do:

`get_student_summary($id) as $r`you should also be passing the person's ID in from here.  I imagine someone clicks a button when they go to this page, so pass it through on that button click to get to that page.

Comment: Hi, if you could can you look at this screenshot, it shows how I do my PHP for pulling the data from the function I have created https://gyazo.com/eef214f474eda3aeee0f33d14ecb2819

Comment: Thanks alot it works now :) I should have posted this question bit early so then I didn't had to worry this much and got an answer quickly hah . Thanks

Comment: No problem!  Good luck, glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

Just specify a user id in the query

```
$user_id = 71;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT a.*,b.*,c.*,d.*,e.* FROM mock_exam_quiz a, mock_exam_student_summary b, mock_exam_users c, mock_exam_questions d, mock_exam_category e WHERE a.quiz_id = b.exam_id AND c.user_id = b.user_id AND d.question_id = b.question_id AND e.category_id = b.category_id AND b.user_id = ".$user_id);
```

or to iterate and have it all in one array with sub-arrays

```
<?php

function get_student_summary() {
    $userList = array();
    $data = array();

    $users = mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM mock_exam_student_summary");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($users)) {
        $userList[] = $row;
    }

    foreach (array_unique($userList) as $user) {

        $tempData = array();

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT a.*,b.*,c.*,d.*,e.* FROM mock_exam_quiz a, mock_exam_student_summary b, mock_exam_users c, mock_exam_questions d, mock_exam_category e WHERE a.quiz_id = b.exam_id AND c.user_id = b.user_id AND d.question_id = b.question_id AND e.category_id = b.category_id AND b.user_id = '".$user."'");

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $tempData[] = $row;
        }

        array_push($data, $tempData)

    }

    return $data;
}

$list = get_student_summary();

// Would Return In Theory
/*
$list = Array(
    Array(

        quiz_name
        category_name
        etc.

        ),
    Array(

        quiz_name
        category_name
        etc.

        ),
    Array(

        quiz_name
        category_name
        etc.

        ),
    )
*/

?>
```

Comment: how do I pass in this id when I do my php call ? So this is how I do currently foreach (get_student_summary() as $r) and then I use $r to pull the data out

Comment: but if I go about doing the way you suggested, how would I be getting the user_id

Comment: Oh, I see what you want, to iterate though each user.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/a81cDIK.png

I think should hopefully pass all the data through, in sub-arrays for each user.

(Take out linebreak in SQL query)

Answer (score 1):

You can individual student detail by passing id parameter in a function and use the id in the sql where clause:

```
get_student_detail ($id){
   global $db;//$db is your database connection
   $singlestudent=array();
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT a.*,b.*,c.*,d.*,e.* FROM mock_exam_quiz a,
                          mock_exam_student_summary b, mock_exam_users c, 
                          mock_exam_questions d, mock_exam_category e 
                          WHERE a.quiz_id = b.exam_id AND c.user_id = b.user_id 
                          AND d.question_id = b.question_id 
                          AND e.category_id = b.category_id AND b.user_id='$id'", $db);
   while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)):
      $singlestudent[] = $data;
   endwhile;  
   return $singlestudent;
}
```

Now you can call by:

```
get_student_detail(12);//Assigning one student whose id = 12;
```

Note: Don't use depracated mysql extension, use mysqli or PDO.